Can anyone tell me anything about this old fold Ganna bike
I picked up this old Ganna folding bike last weekend and was wondering if anyone can tell me anything about it?
The person I got it from said their father bought it in 1970 in Italy and brought it back to the states.


Welcome to the site - I've removed the "value" part of the question because it is considered OT, and the rest of the question is fine.    Cute wee bike !

It's definitely from Italy http://www.ganna-retro.it/it/biciclette/lusso-donna_6_23.htm
and I've posted a question on their website... lets wait and see what happens.

Your bike might be one of the flood of Eastern European "U" folding bikes.
According to the Folding Bike Guy

The 1970s saw a proliferation of folding bike models coming from:

France (Astra, Peugeot, Motobécane, Motoconfort)
Italy (Bianchi, Carnielli, Cinzia, Formicone, Rizzato)
Austria (Dusika, Puch)
West Germany (Heidemann Werke, Hercules, Jobafa, Kalkhoff, Kettler, Kynast, Panther, Rixe, Schauff, Staiger)
East Germany (MIFA)
Netherlands (Batavus, Gazelle)
Poland (Romet, ZZR)
Japan (Bridgestone)
Spain (Beistegui Hermanos, G.A.C., Torrot)
Argentina (Aurora, Bergamasco)
Brazil (Caloi, Monark)
United Kingdom (Raleigh, Dawes, Elswick Hopper)
USA (Schwinn)
USSR (Салют – “Salute” in Russian)
Yugoslavia (Rog), etc.


Most bicycle companies had a folding bike offering during this decade, leading some to call it the “Golden Age of folding bikes .”
There was also a flood of cheap Eastern European so-called “U-frame” folding bikes (so named because the frame was shaped like the letter U) during the ’70s, many sold via mail order or at department stores and service stations.
Most of them carried phony brand names that gave little indication of their true origin of manufacture.

The Folding Bike Guy offers to try to identify your folding bike if you send some good photographs.
